# Prove that if $f(x, y)$ is homogeneous of degree 1, then $f_{xx} f_{yy} = (f_{xy})^2$

Tags: homogeneous-equation

By definition of homogeneity, if $f(x, y)$ is homogeneous of degree $n$, then $$f(tx, ty) = t^nf(x, y)$$

**Problem**

Prove that if $f(x, y)$ is homogeneous of degree $1$, then $f_{xx}(x, y) f_{yy}(x, y) = (f_{xy})^2$

**Attempted solution**

I tried using Euler's theorem on homogeneous functions, which asserts that if $f(x, y)$ is homogeneous of degree $n$, then $$xf_x(x, y) + yf_y(x, y) = nf(x, y)$$

But this didn't lead me to the desired result:

$$xf_x(x, y) + yf_y(x, y) = nf(x, y)$$
$$\frac{xf_x(x, y)}{nf(x, y)} + \frac{yf_y(x, y)}{nf(x, y)} = 0$$
$$???$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the title, you have that $f(x,y)$ is homogeneus of degree 1, so in particular you have $$xf_{x}(x,y)+yf_{y}(x,y)=f(x,y)$$
You can try deriving that expression by $x$ and by $y$ so you get the form of $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$

Comment: I figured it out. You need to differentiate it with respect to x first using the product rule for $xf_x(x, y)$, then differentiate the *original* expression again with respect to y, then combine the two expressions.